# Java.NIO on Write confusion

Tags: java, nio

I have a confusion on the onWrite method of Java NIO, when the selector is ready to write should I:

1: Register/Change a OP_Write

2: If Write returns 0 what should I do?

3: After writing should I Register or Change ops?

The channel is set to Non-Blocking

```
....onAccept register OP_READ

public void onWrite()
{
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(msg.encode());

            while(bb.remaining()!= 0){
                int ret = socketChannel.write(bb);

                if(ret == 0){

                    //Should I register or should I change op?

                    //socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE, null);

                    //selectionKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                }
            }

            //Is it necessary to change op or re-register Read or 0

            //socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, null);
            //selectionKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            //selectionKey.interestOps(0);
}
```

I'm trying to accomplish the lowest latency possible. And the channel will not echo back, it will just read or write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when the selector is ready to write should I:
>
> 1: Register/Change a OP_Write

It's already registered. That doesn't make sense.

> 2: If Write returns 0 what should I do?

Register OP_WRITE.

> 3: After writing should I Register or Change ops?

If it doesn't return zero, deregister OP_WRITE.

> The channel is set to Non-Blocking

Of course, otherwise you couldn't register anything.

Basically you have the entire question back to front. You should *only* register OP_WRITE in case (2). Not all the time. Just write whenever you have something to write, and then look for case 2. *Then,* when OP_WRITE fires, write and look for case 3.

Comment: one more doubt, deregister and register inside the loop?

Comment: Many of them are wrong, or overcomplicated, with unnecessary register/deregister queues, or don't know the difference between cancelling a key and closing a channel, or do them both, or think you can't write anything until OP_WRITE fires. (2) is near the ordinary write code, which is either inside or outside the select loop, depending on when you need to write; (3) is inside the select loop, in the write code that recovers from zero-length writes..